# Need help for convert coordinante in ViroReact

Tags: react-native, viro-react

I am trying build feature measure distance by using Viro-React. I mesuared distance between two node when I click into ARScene. I used getControllerForwardAsync() to do it. But now, I have a issue. I want convert coordinantes at one point in screen of device (x,y) to coordinantes of ARScene (x,y,z) and function getControllerForwardAsync() will receive this coordinantes to input.
How to do it ? Thank All.